# Loading mixed mode assembly from unmanaged code

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, pinvoke, managed-c++

As the title says i want to call a mixed mode assembly from unmanaged code.

To be more precise, i want to load the mixed mode assembly dynamically and then execute some static unmanaged startup code that registers some Managed C++ Wrappers for C# Code.

Is this possible (or do i need to embed the .Net Runtime or use COM?) ?

Has anybody already done this and can share some experience?

PS: If the mixed mode assembly contains a WPF Window will it be started?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the CLR loaded and initialized.  Yes, making a managed class [ComVisible] or hosting the CLR yourself with CorBindToRuntimeEx() is a way to do this.  A very simple way is to export a managed function from your DLL, the C++/CLI compiler embeds a thunk in the code that takes care of initializing the CLR.  Very easy to do but it does not scale well when the interface to your managed code is fat.

```
ref class Bootstrap
{
public:
    static void Initialize() { 
        // etc..
    }
};

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) 
void __stdcall LoadAndInitialize()
{
    Bootstrap::Initialize();
}
```

You could embellish by passing a function pointer to your native interface.  Convert it to a managed delegate with Marshal::GetDelegateForFunctionPointer().  Don't forget to wrap any native declarations with #pragma managed if you do this.

Comment: Will the CLR also be initialized if i do not export a symbol and just execute some static setup code (Registering a native callback)?

Comment: No, the thunk that the C++/CLI compiler generates to support __declspec(dllexport) on a managed function is essential.