# Read C# functions in C++ project

Tags: c#, visual-c++

Good day,

I want to take an existing C# project and wrap functions into a C++/CLI DLL. I need to be able to read this DLL from VB 6. I choose this route because I won't have to register a .net DLL in order to use it with VB 6. Frankly I have no experience with this kind of thing so I would greatly appreciate a good example. I know there are plenty of similar questions like this but I haven't been able to find anything simple enough for me to understand.

Comment: I think your reason for using C++ is erroneous, you have to register **any** DLL with COM in order to use it with VB6, whether it's written in C# or C++ you have to do the same registration.

Comment: If it is a standard DLL that I can register it with regsvr32 instead of regasm though. regasm has given me trouble

Comment: Ok, I thought you were referring to needing the register with COM in general.  I wrote some C++ COM components years ago using the ATL (Active Template Library), so that might be a good place to start.  But it's a lot of work (as I recall).

Answer (score 1):

This is a fairly unwise route to pursue, making C# code [ComVisible] is pretty trivial and Regasm.exe should not scare you.  The usual mistake with Regasm is to forget to use its /codebase option on your dev machine.

If you insist on not taking advantage of this then you'll need to find a way to get the CLR loaded yourself so it can execute your C++/CLI and C# code.  There are three basic ways to do so.  You've written off COM interop and hosting the CLR yourself isn't very practical if the host app is VB6.  You however can take advantage of the C++/CLI compiler's ability to generate unmanaged DLL entrypoint stubs that load the CLR for you and switches to managed code execution.  Do so by writing a static function that you decorate with `__declspec(dllexport)`.  The technique is shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6110820/loading-mixed-mode-assembly-from-unmanaged-code).  Beware that it isn't particularly performant and you'll have to live with the restrictions imposed by the VB6 Declare statement.

Also check this [post-processing tool](https://sites.google.com/site/robertgiesecke/Home/uploads/unmanagedexports) that can inject these stubs directly into a C# assembly.  Not sure how reliable it is, I haven't used it myself.

Comment: I would have liked to use COM interop but I have to distribute this software to workstations that possible don't have .NET framework. I used this method and I managed to get it to work fine on my computer but distribution seems more tricky. What would you do?

Comment: This makes little sense, you *always* must have .NET installed when you want to use C# or C++/CLI.  Whether you use the Regasm approach or this hack.  If it isn't already pre-installed then a simple installer you create with a Setup project gets it done.  The same kind of project that can register the assembly, Register = vsdrpCOMSelfReg

Answer (score 0):

Be a man and make that DLL under a couple of different compilation/linking/function-call-protocol configurations. Then go ahead and try a couple of different referencing configurations in your VB6 project. Post what works. Contribute, go forth!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Export Managed Code as Unmanaged](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/JTeeuwen/ExportManagedCodeasUnmanaged11262005051206AM/ExportManagedCodeasUnmanaged.aspx)

and [C# Project Template for Unmanaged Exports](https://sites.google.com/site/robertgiesecke/)